# Return error after input is incorrect

Tags: php, if-statement

So I have a form. Lets say the form has an input named "uid". Just under neath that I have an empty variable called $warning. This is what I'm attempting to do on submit (in PHP):

```
if ($uid != $uidcheck) {
$warning = 'UID is incorrect';
return;
}
```

However the $warning variable which is now defined isn't showing anything, it's just stopping. I'm aiming to basically do the check, and if the UID is incorrect, go back to the page and display an error which is defined in the $warning variable.

Here's the full code:

```
<form method="post">

                        <input type="hidden" name="uid" value="{$mybb->user['uid']}"><br />
                            <input type="text" name="message" value="" maxlength="35" placeholder="Enter message"> <br /><br />
    <center>{$warning} <br />
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" name="submit">
                        </form>

if(isset($mybb->input['submit']))
{

if($uid != $uidcheck){
    $warning = 'UID is incorrect';
    return;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You return  nothings  you could return  your message

```
if ($uid != $uidcheck) {
 $warning = 'UID is incorrect';
  return $warning;
}
```

or echo somethings

```
if ($uid != $uidcheck) {
 $warning = 'UID is incorrect';
  echo  $warning;
}
```

Comment: I tried the first one, unfortunately it doesn't work. I'm trying to display an error message and end the function, and let the error message remain on the page.

Comment: what do you do wth the returning value  .. your return value is a result for a function that show error message ??  ...  you question is not about this is just about an if and a return  .. if you want show somethings then could be that echo  let you show the result in a page or in console  ..

Comment: I've added in the full code. Sorry about my poor explanation. Here's basically what I aim to do: When a user submits, if the input doesn't match with another variable, end function and return an error to the user on the original page where the form is.

Comment: if you want validate an input you must define an action related  to your form   then in this php code  you could check the posted  value form your form and eventually render  a page of rmessage  .. otherwise you could validate using ajax .. but this are  new question not related  to your original  ., question  .. SO is not a coding service or a personalt tutoring service  ...so the cange of the question that you have done change completly the problem and this is not fair ...  .. i suggest you a simple tutorial for php post form or ajax validation  ..